# python pandas groupby usage for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have 3 data frames with different models and I want count all models in country wise.

```
gold = pd.DataFrame('Country': ['USA', 'india', 'Russia'],'Medals': [15, 3, 9])
silver = pd.DataFrame('Country': ['USA', 'india', 'Russia'],'Medals': [29, 2, 16])
bronze = pd.DataFrame('Country': ['india', 'USA', 'UK'],'Medals': [4, 28, 27])

data=gold.append(silver).append(bronze)
data1=data.groupby( [ "Country", "Medals"]).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the code below? Using `groupby('Country')` and then summing the number of medals for countries.

```
import pandas as pd

gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'india', 'Russia'],'Medals': [15, 3, 9]}) 
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'india', 'Russia'],'Medals': [29, 2, 16]}) 
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['india', 'USA', 'UK'],'Medals': [4, 28, 27]})

print(pd.concat([gold, silver, bronze]).groupby('Country')['Medals'].sum())

Country
Russia    25
UK        27
USA       72
india      9
Name: Medals, dtype: int64
```

Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy0fDqoMJx8) video out if you want more information. I found it to be really helpful.